# Find a value in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to determine (using JQuery) if my `$(this).data` contains an array with a member=x.  `$(this).data` looks like this:

```
  'key1':[1,28,3,4],
  'key2':[5,6,7,8,9],
  'key3':[15,32]
```

Normally, I'd figure on looping through the keys and checking to see if each value array contained x, but JQuery has all these weird and wonderful functions, I thought there might be an easier way.

Comment: This is not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really elegant, but this works:

```
var notfound = true;
$.each($(this).data, function(key, arr) {
    return notfound = ($.inArray(x, arr) === -1);
});
```

and your answer will be in `notfound`

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

wonderful functions :)

Edit: I think you still needs to wrap inArray in something like

```
$.each( yourArray, functionWithinArray() );
```